# PHP Syntax with variables

Tags: php, variables, syntax, shopp

I am using the wordpress shopp plugin to  sell products on my site. On my template file, I am using a shopp short code to display a particular category. It looks like this:

```
<?php shopp('catalog','category','load=true&id=16'); ?>
```

I would like the number 16 to be changeable, so I have stored the correct dynamic number in a variable as follows:

```
<?php $shopid = get_field('store_id'); ?>
```

The Variable `$shopid` is the correct number that should replace the '`16`' above. The question is, how do I place a variable in the shopp shortcode? I tried as follows without luck:

```
<?php shopp('catalog','category','load=true&id=$shopid'); ?>
```

Any ideas how to pull this off?

Comment: <?php shopp('catalog','category',"load=true&id=$shopid"); ?>
try using the [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) or the [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) command next time to see what's wrong with values

Comment: A Shopp shortcode would look like `[catalog-collection id='1']`. What you are referring to is a `shopp('object', 'property', 'options')` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within [single-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) variables are not getting replaced by their values:

> **Note:** Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Use [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) or [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) instead:

```
shopp('catalog','category',"load=true&id=$shopid")
shopp('catalog','category','load=true&id='.$shopid)
```

Comment: thanks! perfect, no more answers please this did it! (just have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer)

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
<?php shopp('catalog','category',"load=true&id=$shopid"); ?>
```

Notice the [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Or:

```
<?php shopp('catalog','category','load=true&id=' . $shopid); ?>
```

This is [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).